# Number of group homomorphism from the group $D_8$ to $\Bbb Q^{\times} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers, dihedral-groups

How does one determine the number of group homomorphism from $ D_{8}$ to $\Bbb Q^{\times}$?

---

For any homomorphism $f$, $o(f(x))$ divides $ o(x) $, in case of both being finite.

Here $\Bbb Q^{\times}$ has only two elements with finite order while each element in $ D_{8} $ is of finite order.

And in $ D_{8} $, for generators $y$ and $x$, we have $yx = xy^{-1}$ where $ y^{2}= e = x^{4}$ .

I need a hint to proceed further.

Comment: A homomorphism is defined by its values on $x$ and $y$. And as you said, you must send $x$ and $y$ onto elements of finite order of $\mathbb{Q}^*$. Is there a lot of possibilities ?

Comment: A couple of things - when you write the group $D_{\star}$ you should morally say the order since there is disagreement whether $\star$ is the order of the group, or whether it is symmetries of the $\star$-gon. Also ``\mathbb{Q}`` typesets the rationals nicely.

Comment: If you read French, you can perhaps be helped by "Homomorphismes partant d'un groupe diédral" on this page : https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_des_groupes/Groupes_di%C3%A9draux

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is abelian, so any such homomorphism factors through the abelianization of $D_8$. Once you compute the abelianization things get much easier.